# How to make my button work after I've been writing?

Tags: javascript, html

Im trying to make some kind of "blog" buttons. I want to click on a button, and then it will write in my textarea for whatever button I clicked. But for some reason, it wont add if I've been writing or done anything in the textarea before I clicked.

```
<button onClick="knapp('lank')">Länk</button>
<button onClick="knapp('fet')">Fet</button>
<button onClick="knapp('bild')">Bild</button>
<br><br>
<textarea id='knappar' rows="10" cols="50"></textarea>
```

And my scriptcode is

```
function knapp(value)
{   
var text;

switch(value){
    case "fet":
    text = '<b></b>';
    break;
    case "lank":
    text = '<a href="https://www.hemsida.com">Klicka här</a>';
    break;
    case "bild":
    text = '<img src="https://www.hemsida.com">';
    break;
}
var pp = document.createTextNode(text);
document.getElementById('knappar').appendChild(pp);
```

}

So when I click the button, it writes and append. But if I've been writing, or deleting something, it wont work.

I'm fairly new with Javascript, so sorry for noob question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using

```
document.getElementById('knappar').value += text;
```

instead of

```
var pp = document.createTextNode(text);
document.getElementById('knappar').appendChild(pp);
```

---

Full Example

```js
function knapp(value) {
    var text;

    switch (value) {
        case "fet":
            text = '<b></b>';
            break;
        case "lank":
            text = '<a href="https://www.hemsida.com">Klicka här</a>';
            break;
        case "bild":
            text = '<img src="https://www.hemsida.com">';
            break;
    }
    var pp = document.createTextNode(text);
    document.getElementById('knappar').value += text;
}
```

```html
<button onClick="knapp('lank')">Länk</button>
<button onClick="knapp('fet')">Fet</button>
<button onClick="knapp('bild')">Bild</button>
<br><br>
<textarea id='knappar' rows="10" cols="50"></textarea>
```